# How to secure Oracle connection for a .Net/C# Application?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

We have a .Net/C# application connected to Oracle 18C XE.

The application connects to Oracle using the following code :

```
    dim ConnectionString as string =  "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" _
                                    & "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST="& Some IP Adress & ")(PORT=1521)))" _
                                    & "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));" _
                                    & "User Id=" & Username & ";Password=" & Password & ";"
                                    
    dim Connection as new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(ConnectionString)
    
    Connection.Open()
```

Can anyone please tell how to encrypt this connection between the application and the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption and data integrity checking are handled through the Oracle TNS networking stack. Parameters must be configured in both the client and server sqlnet.ora files. See here for details:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-network-data-encryption-and-integrity.html#GUID-7F12066A-2BA1-476C-809B-BB95A3F727CF
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/native-network-encryption-for-database-connections

Additionally, I would recommend using an Oracle Wallet to hold the username and password and not storing them anywhere in the application code or configuration files.

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-2239A690-3F63-4B1D-A09B-94B8411700D5